# How to generate Outlook email from a shared mailbox

Tags: vba, excel

I figured out how to send the email but having it sent from the shared mailbox has been a huge challenge.

I tried `.SentonBehalfofName` which ends up showing my primary account address in the properties

I followed a tutorial to loop you through account number and change `.sendusingccount`.
There is no other account number since it is a shared mailbox so changing `outapp.sessions.accounts.item` does nothing.

Comment: Is there no solution yet for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add the shared mailbox to your Outlook profile then there will be an account number.

[Add an email account to Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-email-account-to-outlook-6e27792a-9267-4aa4-8bb6-c84ef146101b)